# Executing segment codes from MASM with JMP

Tags: debugging, assembly, masm

I would like to execute the following commands in MASM:

```
jmp far PTR 0:61Dh 


jmp far ptr 2000h:0


jb short near ptr 106h
```

The first two are producing  error A2206: missing operator in expression

and the third, error A2028: expression must be a code address.

If anyone could advise as to how to make these functions work in MASM I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Is the trailing comma in your first one just a typo in your problem statement, or is it in your original MASM file?

Comment: Just a typo, ill edit that out now

Comment: I can see that I could use 

fpdw dw 0,61Dh

    push 1000h
    push 0
    retf

    jmp fpdd

    jmp dword ptr fpdw

      I would like to know what can be used for the near instruction?